# Get the detected generic type inside Jackson's JsonDeserializer

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, jackson-databind

For external reasons, all java `Map`s in my system can only be received as *lists* of key-value pairs from the clients, e.g. a `Map<String, Book>` will actually be received as Json-serialized `List<MapEntry<String, Book>>`. This means I need to customize my Json deserialization process to expect this representation of maps.

The problem is that `JsonDeserializer` makes me implement

```
deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
```

method which has no access to the detected generic type it's supposed to deserialize (`Map<String, Book>` in the example above). Without that info, I can't in turn deserialize `List<MapEntry<String, Book>>` without loosing type safety.

I was looking at [Converter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/Converter.html) but it gives even less context.

E.g.

```
public Map<K,V> convert(List<MapToListTypeAdapter.MapEntry<K,V>> list) {
    Map<K,V> x = new HashMap<>();
    list.forEach(entry -> x.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    return x;
}
```

But this will potentially create dangerous maps that will throw a `ClassCastException` on retrieval, as there's no way to check the type is actually sensible.
Is there a way to get around this?

As an example of what I'd expect, Gson's [`JsonDeserializer`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) looks like this:

```
T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
```

I.e. it gives access to the expected type in a sane way.

Comment: Did you got this issue because your project is using Jackson for serialization/deserialization, and you are getting response from external system that is using Moxy? if yes, then I have the same issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got an answer on the [Jackson Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-user/BR_USCluxng) directly from the author.

The key thing to understand is that **`JsonDeserializer`s are initiated/contextualized once**, and they receive the full type and other information at that moment only. To get a hold of this info, the deserializer needs to implement `ContextualDeserializer`. Its `createContextual` method is called to initialize a deserializer instance, and has access to the `BeanProperty` which also gives the full `JavaType`.

So it could look something like this in the end:

```
public class MapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private JavaType type;

    public MapDeserializer() {
    }

    public MapDeserializer(JavaType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext deserializationContext, BeanProperty beanProperty) throws JsonMappingException {
        //beanProperty is null when the type to deserialize is the top-level type or a generic type, not a type of a bean property
        JavaType type = deserializationContext.getContextualType() != null 
            ? deserializationContext.getContextualType()
            : beanProperty.getMember().getType();            
        return new MapDeserializer(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Map deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        //use this.type as needed
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Registered and used as normal:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Map.class, new MapDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: I'm surprised no one upvoted before. Nobody has used this? Is this answer duplicated elsewhere? Anyway... thanks so much!

Comment: @FerranMaylinch Glad you found it helpful :)